# Why don't you see Nunu played in mid?

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to know why Nunu is never played mid? In my opinion his kit would allow for nice sustain (passive saving mana and consume allowing to heal).

What stops him from being effective there?

Comment: Didn't we just have this conversation at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58485/why-is-leblanc-forgotten-amongst-the-pros ?

Comment: Hi @kahlens, this question was closed as Not Constructive because it's asking for opinions and discussion, which is more suited for a forum than our Q&A-focused site. Our site focuses on solving problems that gamers face. If you were to edit your question to be about the difficulties you personally faced while playing him in mid and asked for advice based on your experience, then it could be a candidate for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think a Nunu top would be more viable as its the lane based around sustain. If Nunu went mid he would get bursted anytime he went in to farm or use his consume, whereas top would be different as there is more melee champions allowing safer farming.

Comment: Well what would you build to a Nunu top?

Comment: Try this guide: <http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/nunu-ice-cold-killer-ap-laner-123444> 
For the record, I've never tried Nunu solo lane before, but this guide seems pretty popular so it must be do-able at the very least. I use Nunu support.

Answer (score 1):

his e has a 1.0 ap ratio, as well as hit ulti have a 2.8 to 1 ratio, but since his E is the only thing thata would do damage on a consistent basis on a 6 second cooldown, its not worth it to play him as a carry, as that is his only reliable source of damage. But trust me, building ap and watching your E chunk everything known to man for the first 20 minutes is very very fun.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because even with his strong pressure he can lose to a ranged ap champion like ryze, cass, morgana or ahri (who are very strong atm).

If you max iceball you have little sustain compared to the harass they can dish out, but if you max consume then you don't have as much damage to work with.

I think he is strong but I believe that is what holds him back as a mid laner.